# Pybind11: Create numpy view of data

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I want to create numpy view of the data in a C++ class.

But the following makes a copy instead of a view.

The python test:

```
import _cpp
a = _cpp.A()
print(a)
a.view()[:] = 100  # should make it all 100.
print(a)
```

Result:

```
40028064 0 0 0  // Fail: Modifying a.mutable_data() in C++ doesn't 
                //       change _data[4]
40028064 0 0 0  // Fail: Modifying a.view() in Python 3 doesn't 
                //       change data in a
```

The C++ line `a.mutable_data()[0] = -100;` doesn't change the 0th element to -100. This shows `py::array_t<int> a(4, &_data[0]);` creates a copy instead of a view of `int _data[4];`

Modifying the array `a.view()` doesn't change the data in `a` to 100s.
This shows that `a.view()` is a copy instead of a view of the data in `a`.

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "pybind11/pybind11.h"
#include "pybind11/numpy.h"

namespace py = pybind11;
class A {
public:
    A() {}
    std::string str() {
        std::stringstream o;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) o << _data[i] << " ";
        return o.str();
    }
    py::array view() {
        py::array_t<int> a(4, &_data[0]);
        a.mutable_data()[0] = -100;
        return a;
    }
    int _data[4];
};

PYBIND11_MODULE(_cpp, m) {
    py::class_<A>(m, "A")
        .def(py::init<>())
        .def("__str__", &A::str)
        .def("view", &A::view, py::return_value_policy::automatic_reference);
}
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(test_pybind11)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

# Find packages.
set(PYTHON_VERSION 3)
find_package( PythonInterp ${PYTHON_VERSION} REQUIRED )
find_package( PythonLibs ${PYTHON_VERSION} REQUIRED )

# Download pybind11
set(pybind11_url https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/archive/stable.zip)

set(downloaded_file ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/pybind11-stable.zip)
file(DOWNLOAD ${pybind11_url} ${downloaded_file})
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E tar xzf ${downloaded_file}
        SHOW_PROGRESS)
file(REMOVE ${downloaded_file})

set(pybind11_dir ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/pybind11-stable)
add_subdirectory(${pybind11_dir})
include_directories(${pybind11_dir}/include)

# Make python module
pybind11_add_module(_cpp main.cpp)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the comment in [issue 308](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/pull/308) that says `py::cast(self)`, I try `py::cast(*this)`.

That works. I feel a bit uneasy about invalidation of views, but numpy does that the same way.

Python test:

```
import _cpp
import numpy as np
a = _cpp.A()
print(a)
a.view()[:] = 100  # should make it all 100.
print(a)
```

Test result:

```
1480305816 32581 19420784 0 // original data of `a`
100 100 100 100 // It works: changing `a.view()` changes data of `a`.
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "pybind11/pybind11.h"
#include "pybind11/numpy.h"

namespace py = pybind11;
class A {
public:
    A() {}
    std::string str() {
        std::stringstream o;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) o << _data[i] << " ";
        return o.str();
    }
    py::array view() {
        return py::array(4, _data, py::cast(*this));  // <---
    }
    int _data[4];
};

PYBIND11_MODULE(_cpp, m) {
    py::class_<A>(m, "A")
        .def(py::init<>())
        .def("__str__", &A::str)
        .def("view", &A::view, py::return_value_policy::reference_internal);
}
```

I use `reference_internal` to make the life time of `a.view()` tie to  life time of `a`.

---

*View is invalidate upon deleting the parent object.*

After deleting `a` in the python test, python will garbage collect the data of `a` at an indefinite time. This means if I previously store the view by `b = a.view()`, `b` is invalidated after `a` is deleted.

I try to make `a._data` a numpy array at the C++ side but that doesn't help the invalidation.

main.cpp:

```
class A {
public:
    A() : _data(4, new int[4]) {}
    std::string str() {
        std::stringstream o;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) o << _data.data()[i] << " ";
        return o.str();
    }
    py::array view() {
        return py::array(4, _data.data(), py::cast(*this));
    }
    py::array_t<int> _data;
};
```

Python Test:

```
import _cpp
import numpy as np
a = _cpp.A()
print(a)
a.view()[:] = 100  # should make it all 100.
b = a.view()
print('b is base?', b.base is None)
del a
print('b is base after deleting a?', b.base is None)

c = np.zeros(4)
print('c is base?', c.base is None)
d = c.view()
print('d is base?', d.base is None)
del c
print('d is base after deleting c?', d.base is None)
```

Result:

```
-6886248 32554 16092080 0 
// c++ code's management of views
b is base? False
b is base after deleting a? False
// numpy's management of views
c is base? True
d is base? False
d is base after deleting c? False
```

Looks like when the base numpy array is deleted, the ownership of the memory is not transferred to one of the views. Same is true for the C++ class. I guess I will stick with the previous solution.

Comment: It works and it is a complete answer. The view is invalidated upon deleting the original object `a`. But numpy's view seems to be invalidated under the same condition. So I guess that is fine.

Comment: I added a few words in the  answer to clarify why this works now. hopefully it is more clear now.